# Elevate zoom on gallery images

Tags: magento-1.9, gallery, zoom

I successfully managed to make my base photo have zoom but when I change my image the zoom is still referring to the base image how can I fix this.
I tried with attribute gallery but it's not working

My code to change product images through thumbnails

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/easy-slider.js');?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      (function($){
          $(document).ready(function($){
              $(".more-views").easySlider({
                  mainImg: "p.product-image-zoom img",
                  btnNext: ".jm-product-lemmon .next",
                  btnPrev: ".jm-product-lemmon .prev",
                  animate: true,
                  loop: true,
                  speed: 300,
                  width: 100,
                  width_img: 78,
                  start: <?php echo $start?>
              });
          });
      })(jQuery);
      // ]]>
  </script>
```

my code for zoom

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.elevatezoom.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    (function($) {
        $("#image").elevateZoom({
            scrollZoom: false,
            borderColour: "#eee",
            tintColour: "#eee",
            zoomWindowWidth: 450,
            zoomWindowHeight: 450,
            gallery: 'jm-product-lemmon',
            galleryActiveClass: 'active'
        });
    })(jQuery);
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to disable the zoom and initialise it again on the active image.

*You may need to change some of the selectors below.*

#### Disable zoom

```
$('#image').removeData('elevateZoom');
$('.zoomWrapper img.zoomed').unwrap();
$('.zoomContainer').remove();
```

So it goes like this:

1. On page load you initialise the zoom
2. When the carousel changes slide you disable the zoom
3. When the next slide loads you initialise zoom on the active image (or when the user taps on the zoom icon  or however your zoom is initialised)

Comment: ok but where do i put it? and what about zoomWrapper do i have to create it?

Comment: Hopefully the slider you're using has a callback you can hook onto when the slide changes? If not then it may be more difficult. `.zoomWrapper` is the parent of your zoomed image, you may not need this. I don't think I did but quite a few people online did.

Comment: i dont use zoomWrapper so i think i dont need it
what do you mean by callback what should i look for

https://github.com/bsy/easyslider

Comment: Does the slider you're using have callback methods? If you don't have much experience with Javascript I'd advise against trying to get multiple plugins working together as it usually causes problems you'll need to debug and fix.